# Can I check which users ran which updates?

Tags: users, errors, updates, wp-cli, management

We have a site that was previously updated to 4.8.0. Two of us who normally perform updates did not have the right permissions to run the 4.8.1 update.
Using wp-cli `wp core update`

```
Error: Could not create directory.
```

I did successfully run the update after a `setfacl` command.

I'm trying to determine who and when a WordPress update was made. Are there any wp-cli commands to display such information?

For example: `wp core version --extra` shows a few handy tidbits, but can it be appended to roll out additional forensic information like dates and users?
[image]

Comment: I believe the answer to this will require linux knowledge rather than WP knowledge, specifically, you need to go to the location of that folder or its enclosing owner, and see which user owns it